# Debian - after install folder structure in /home/user differs across PCs

Tags: debian, nautilus

I installed Debian Stretch on two Laptops. One has UEFI, while the other has BIOS - this is the only difference regarding the Debian installation process (I used graphical install).

After the install BIOS PC already has some basic file structure set up in Nautilus:

[image]

While other hasn't got the basic folder structure inside home folder. Also emblems on folders are missing in Nautilus:

[image]

Has anyone got an idea why this could happen?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -la /etc/skel` of both laptop's.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I only have the UEFI one here (it is the one that doesn't have the folders set up). In folder `/etc/skel` there are files `.bashrc`, `.profile` and  `.bash_logout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the default user directories you can use the following command  :

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

The list of the directories that were created by the command `xdg-user-dirs-update` can also be read with:

```
cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

There is a description how the [`xdg-user-dirs`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/xdg-user-dirs) work.

> `xdg-user-dirs` is a tool to help manage "well known" user directories like the desktop folder and the music folder. It also handles localization (i.e. translation) of the filenames.
>
> The way it works is that `xdg-user-dirs-update` is run very early in the login phase. This program reads a configuration file, and a set of default directories. It then creates localized versions of these directories in the users home directory and sets up a config file in `$(XDG_CONFIG_HOME)/user-dirs.dirs` (XDG_CONFIG_HOME defaults to ~/.config) that applications can read to find these directories.

Comment: I used `xdg-user-dirs-update` and my folder structure was set up.  It looks like in some cases Debian installer fails at executing this command. Before I executed the command the content of `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` was empty, but now it holds lines like `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"`. @Hunter S. Thompson After execution there was still no folders present in `/etc/skel`, so I haven't tried your method yet.

Answer (score 1):

There should be all the preset folder's like Music, Pictures, Documents etc in `/etc/skel`, so that when you add a new user you would get the preset folder's in `/home/$USER/`.

It is odd why one installation would follow this step and another not.

You could just re create the preset folder's in `/etc/skel`. So that when you add a new user you will get the preset folder's in your home directory.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/skel/Documents/ /etc/skel/Downloads/ /etc/skel/Templates/ /etc/skel/Videos/ /etc/skel/Music/ /etc/skel/Pictures/ /etc/skel/Public/
```

From my experience, I always had to create the folder's in `/etc/skel/`, I never got them preset.